# glowing & pulsating text for IE8 & IE9 - css-only solution=

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Is there any css only solution, to make this pulsating-glow effect work on IE8/9 or atleast 9?

```
.glow-texte {
color:#fff;
text-shadow:0 0 2px #fff;
animation:texte 2.4s linear 2s 20;
-moz-animation:texte 2.4s linear 2s 20;
-webkit-animation:texte 2.4s linear 2s 20;
}

.glow-texteEven {
color:#fff;
text-shadow:0 0 2px #fff;
animation:texte 2.4s linear 1s 20;
-moz-animation:texte 2.4s linear 1s 20;
-webkit-animation:texte 2.4s linear 1s 20;
}

.glow-texteOdd {
color:#fff;
text-shadow:0 0 2px #fff;
animation:texte 2.4s linear 2.2s 20;
-moz-animation:texte 2.4s linear 2.2s 20;
-webkit-animation:texte 2.4s linear 2.2s 20;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately you are trying to get css3 stuffs to work on browser which was built when css3 was not really thought of yet. although the shadow effect should work on ie9, sadly ie8 fails. this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449502/html5-and-css3-for-ie7-and-ie8 should give you some idea but it does use js unfortunately.

Comment: try css3 pie as well... sorry i forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0):

**CSS3 pie** (as Sai suggested) will get you most of the way there (shadow, styling, etc): [PIE makes Internet Explorer 6-9 capable of rendering several of the most useful CSS3 decoration features.](http://css3pie.com/) But it will not get you all the way there (it will get the shadowing effect, in this example).

IE8 is just too limited to try and do it in CSS alone. For the animated portion, you can use JavaScript. **For an example of how to do that, please see this answer: [Convert CSS3 animation into JQuery for use in IE8 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20936054/convert-css3-animation-into-jquery-for-use-in-ie8-and-above)**

You want to check if the browser supports the technology with [Modernizr.js](http://modernizr.com/) and then you can chose to do it in CSS if it does support it OR use JavaScript to do what you can't in CSS. If you use JQuery, make sure you use a version older than 2.0:

> [jQuery Core: Version 1.9 and Beyond](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/06/28/jquery-core-version-1-9-and-beyond/) - jQuery 2.0 (early 2013, not long after 1.9): This version will support the same APIs as jQuery 1.9 does, but removes support for IE 6/7/8 oddities such as borked event model, IE7 “attroperties”, HTML5 shims, etc.

This other solution may also be of help to you finding your solution: [CSS3 Animation in IE8/9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854761/css3-animation-in-ie8-9)