# CSS3 animated spinner workaround for IE

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3, font-awesome

Is there anyway to get CSS3 spin animation on IE8 and above? What I want to do is to get Font Awesome (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/) animated spinner to work with older version of IE.

Is it possible to do it with javascript or jQuery plugin?

Thank you.

Comment: Please see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612352/when-using-css-transitions-animations-etc-whats-the-best-way-to-fall-back-to

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try the javascript plugin, [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/)**

On its site it says it `Works in all major browsers, including IE6` so it should work with IE8.

It's really simple to use, I use it all the time.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like spin.js, the alternative is using a fallback and insert an animated gif in those browsers.